# Ignoring -Inf values in arrays using numpy/scipy in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have an NxM array in numpy that I would like to take the log of, and ignore entries that were negative prior to taking the log. When I take the log of negative entries, it returns -Inf, so I will have a matrix with some -Inf values as a result. I then want to sum over the columns of this matrix, but ignoring the -Inf values -- how can I do this?

For example,

```
mylogarray = log(myarray)
# take sum, but ignore -Inf?
sum(mylogarray, 0)
```

I know there's nansum and I need the equivalent, something like infsum.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [masked arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html):

```
>>> a = numpy.array([2, 0, 1.5, -3])
>>> b = numpy.ma.log(a)
>>> b
masked_array(data = [0.69314718056 -- 0.405465108108 --],
             mask = [False  True False  True],
       fill_value = 1e+20)

>>> b.sum()
1.0986122886681096
```

Comment: can you please expand on this? I don't understand the example. How did you initialize the masked array above?

Comment: @user248237 - The `numpy.ma.log`, etc, functions will automatically create a masked array where anything that results in a `inf` or `nan` is masked.  This is a bit less explicit, though, so you can instead do this: `a = np.ma.masked_where(a == np.inf, a)`, and then just do `b = np.log(a)` (or any other function). Alternatively, you can avoid masked arrays and just do `np.log(a[a != np.inf]).sum()` (You can index by boolean arrays, it's much cleaner and faster than the `filter`-based answers.)

Comment: @user248237 I didn't initialize the masked array explicitly. `a` is just a normal, non-masked array. `ma.log` masks all values where the (real) logarithm is undefined. Then the resulting masked array `b` is treated roughly as if the masked entries weren't there.

Comment: I got `AttributeError: 'SingleBlockManager' object has no attribute 'log'`

Answer (score 40):

The easiest way to do this is to use [`numpy.ma.masked_invalid()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_invalid.html):

```
a = numpy.log(numpy.arange(15))
a.sum()
# -inf
numpy.ma.masked_invalid(a).sum()
# 25.19122118273868
```

Comment: In case you still have sum results `inf` even with mask, try change the `dtype` to `np.float64`

Comment: This helped me to filter out `np.inf` from mean calculations...thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Alternative to using masked arrays....

```
import numpy as np
myarray = np.array([2, 0, 1.5, -3])
mylogarray = np.log(myarray) # The log of negative numbers is nan, 0 is -inf
summed = mylogarray[np.isfinite(mylogarray)].sum() # isfinite will exclude inf and nan
print(f'Sum of logged array is: {summed}')
>>> Sum of logged array is: 1.0986122886681096
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `filter()`:

```
>>> array
array([  1.,   2.,   3., -Inf])
>>> sum(filter(lambda x: x != float('-inf'), array))
6.0
```

Comment: Is this considered a vectorized operation? Is there a more efficient way? I need to do this many times in my code and wanted a vectorized approach

Comment: Are you asking if this is done in-place with iterators? No. Is there a more efficient way? AFAIK, you'd have to loop through the array as there's no filter function that returns an iterator, unless you write one.

Comment: I don't think the filter code works for NxM arrays.. it seems to onlyu work for 1xM vectors.

Comment: The "numpythonic" way to do `filter(lambda x: x != float('-inf'), array)` is just `x[x != np.inf]` Using list comprehensions, `filter`, etc, is much slower on numpy arrays than it is on lists.  Because of that, numpy arrays have a number of facilities to avoid explicitly looping through and operating on each element.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can index your matrix and use:

```
import numpy as np;
matrix = np.array([[1.,2.,3.,np.Inf],[4.,5.,6.,np.Inf],[7.,8.,9.,np.Inf]]);
print matrix[:,1];
print sum(filter(lambda x: x != np.Inf,matrix[:,1]));
print matrix[1,:];
print sum(filter(lambda x: x != np.Inf,matrix[1,:]));
```